# При перераспределении места на жестком диске перестал работать grub и не видны разделы

Tags: windows, ubuntu, восстановление, dual-boot, gparted

На ноутбуке стояла Win10 и Ubuntu(вроде 16.04). Сегодня использовал Aomei Partition Assistant для увеличения места на диске C за счет диска K и увелечение места для разделов Ubuntu за счет диска F(порядок расположения вроде такой был C->K->F-> разделы Ubuntu). После запуска программы и выполненной ей первой перезагрузки появилось что-то вроде консоли с надписью Minimal BASH like line editing is supported. Cейчас загрузился с Live CD. Очень важно восстановить данные разделов Ubuntu(а в лучшем случае просто работу Ubuntu). TestDisk при быстром сканировании не помог. Раньше под разделы Ubuntu было отведено 45гб, сейчас Gparted показывает нераспределенные 60гб. [image: screen shot]
UPDATE:: TestDisk: помогло глубокое сканирование для восстановления файлов.